# BSOD: hal.dll +12A3B

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have a Toshiba Satellite L350D with Windows 7 x64 which is throwing BSOD hal.dll +12A3B with the following error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
When i got the laptop in my hands the temps was too high and i thought that the problem was this. So:

I cleaned the CPU and replaced the thermal paste and now the temps are around 45-60 Celcius.

I also:

- Replaced the hdd with a brand new SSD. (clean install)
- Checked the CPU with Intel CPU diagnostic tool.
- Checked RAM's with windows utility.

all seems fine...

This is a screenshot of whocrashed utility
[image: whocrashed]

and [this](http://tinyurl.com/orulumk) is the memory dump (2nd one in the screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bugcheck 0x124](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates a fatal error:

> The WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000124. This
>   bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred.

From the dump I can see that you get this timeout error: **BUSLG_GENERIC_ERR_*_NOTIMEOUT_ERR**

```
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa80045f8038
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d0882501b8eb86
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 5/6/2015 17:49:56 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80045f80b8
Section       @ fffffa80045f8190
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : BUS error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 3
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000006fd
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80045f8100
Section       @ fffffa80045f8250
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : fd 06 00 00 00 08 02 00 - 9d e3 00 00 ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa80045f8250

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80045f8148
Section       @ fffffa80045f82d0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : BUSLG_GENERIC_ERR_*_NOTIMEOUT_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 5)
  Status      : 0xb20000300c000e0f
```

Maybe the heat damaged the Intel Pentium T3400 too much and this causes now the crash.

Comment: Is there a chance for the CPU to be dead and also pass the intel diagnostic?

Comment: The salient lines in that output are "Machine Check Exception" and "BUS error". These indicate very serious errors in the platform (but not in the CPU).

Comment: I already ordered a new CPU from ebay... Can you please give me more details?

Comment: I looked at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) and found that Some of the main hardware problems that cause MCEs include:

    * System bus errors: (error communicating between the processor and the motherboard).
    * Memory errors: parity checking detects when a memory error has occurred. Error correction code (ECC) can correct limited memory errors so that processing can continue.
    * Cache errors in the processor.

Comment: Memory in a laptop (or ordinary desktop machine) has neither parity checking nor ECC. The CPU might fix the problem, but usually MCEs are due to the chipset or something beyond it.

Comment: I got 2 memory sticks and i tried with the one and then with the other one. Both did BSOD's. So you give more odds in the motherboard and less the CPU? :(

Comment: This is no RAM issue, the CPU/motherboard has an issue, but this is hard to debug what causes it. Replace the laptop, it is several years old now.

Comment: Isn't mine... My friend already paid enough to upgrade ram and ssd! I am now waiting for a new cpu from ebay... I ll let you know soon...

Comment: Today i replaced the CPU and in the 1st boot I received the same BSOD again. Can you help me with which part of the motherboard is faulty?

Comment: this can be so many things (CPU Socket, other parts around the socket which were damaged because of the extreme heat) which is hard to debug. The SSD can be re used again. Try to sell the CPU and the RAM again on ebay and buy a new laptop and use the SSD here.

Comment: Hehe! Yeah that I was thinking also... Thanks a lot @magicandre1981